# PHP Website VIdeo Conferencing Integration

Tags: php, video-streaming, video-conferencing

In a PHP project, I need to implement feature of Video Conferencing.

I did google and found few options as below:

1. http://openmeetings.apache.org/index.html
2. http://codecanyon.net/item/video-chat/5492482

Also, i have read about HTML5 option, however i came to know that still only few browsers support that feature hence we also need to have flash as alternative.

Can anyone suggest me alternative? We are ready for open source as well as to purchase licence.

Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try VLine.

Its based on WebRTC protocol and I have used it in few projects, worked great.

[Vline](https://vline.com/)

Using this you can create Video chat rooms and one to one or one to many conference calls.

Comment: Thanks, do you have idea about price?

Comment: @AnkurRaiyani Its free. Check the Why use a vLine link? section on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC is not currently supported by default PC browsers (Internet Explorer for Windows and Safari for Mac OS).
http://www.videochat-scripts.com/webrtc-videochat-and-conferencing-support/

To be able to provide service for all site users you should consider RTMP solutions.

For quick setup and testing you could try WordPress video conferencing plugins:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?type=term&q=video+conference